# Group and center images of varying width?

Tags: css

I have 4 images that need to be "grouped" then centered horizontally.  These are letters in a word. They cannot be combined into a single image.

Here is what I have right now:

```css
#imageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#images {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#imageContainer img {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="images">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/105x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/135x100/000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

The desired behavior would look more like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `img` is an **inline level tag** so you can use `text-align: center` on them as in @acoder's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
#imageContainer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I only add  `text-align: center;` in parent div. And It is working. Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `#images{display:flex;align-items:center}`