# Fill width of a div containing a horizontal array of images with css

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` with multiple varying-width, uniform-height images.  The images are horizontally arranged with no gaps between them.

What I have so far:

```css
#imageContainer {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#images {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 2px;
}
#imageContainer img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="images">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/420x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x100/000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like for all of the images to scale to fit within my `div`, filling it, but I can't seem to find where I can do this with multiple images.

I question is basically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700543/group-and-center-images-of-varying-width) but with a twist of also scaling to fit.

Comment: min-width:0 to image?

Comment: @afif is right and for scaling `100%` width will make your image responsive https://jsfiddle.net/mb6ce812/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want a gap in your box you should remove width/position from the inner `#images` container. To make the images scale down you can add a `min-width`. If you want the images to not distort add an `object-fit`:

```css
#imageContainer {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#images {
  display: flex;
  margin: 2px;
}
#imageContainer img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px;
  /* Important bits: */
  min-width: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="images">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/420x100/000/fff" alt="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x100/000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

*(Btw, centering using `left` + `transform` can cause blurriness in some rendering engines.)*

Comment: After applying this, I see what you mean about the gaps.  The container maintains the height of the original image.  Is there a way to reduce that to just fit the scaled image height as well?  I need the `width` as it limits the width of the inner container.  (Maybe I can do a padding on the outer container?)

Comment: @gregsdennis: I cannot think of a quick way to get the correct height. Maybe you will have to calculate and apply that yourself in JS. (Total aspect ratio would be the sum of all widths by the height, this can then be applied to the width of the container to get the correct height, assuming that all images are the same height)

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using Bootstrap for most of my front-end styling as they provide lots of nifty "features" that make it easy for me to create a nice looking front-end without having to spend hours with CSS trying to get it looking perfect or making it scalable to multiple viewports.

Hence, here is how I would solve it using Bootstrap-4. [(Here is a Codepen link)](https://codepen.io/bigbenbeer/pen/KKVRwQR)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row outline-primary">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff" class="img-fluid h-100">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x100/000/fff" class="img-fluid h-100">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/420x100/000/fff" class="img-fluid h-100">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x100/000/fff" class="img-fluid h-100">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All of those images are the same width.  I have varying widths.

Comment: @gregsdennis even if you change the width, each image within the row has the same width and height (i.e. they scale). You can even use the `w-` and `h-` specifiers within Bootstrap to cap the width/height of the row or container to a fixed sixe. Just as a side note, why the downvote? Is there some way I can improve my answer to at least "no vote" status?